# Passing two parameters into remove_if predicate

Tags: c++, algorithm, tuples, predicate, yandex

```
void Print (vector<pair<int, string>> v) {
    for(auto& p : v) {
        auto[_int, _str] = Unpack(p);
        cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int, string>> v = {{1,"b"}, {2, "z"}, {1, "a"}};

    Print(v);
    /* 
    1 b 
    2 z
    1 a 
    */

    auto predicate = [](const int _int, const string _str) {

        return _int != 1 || _str == "b";

    };

    auto it = remove_if(begin(v), end(v), predicate);
    v.erase(it, end(v));

    Print(v);
    /* I want:a
    1 a
    */

}
```

So this is a part of Yandex's C++ course: [coursera link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/c-plus-plus-yellow/programming/n1Nbg/kursovoi-proiekt)

The predicate is pre-defined and I can't change it. It's a lambda function taking 2 arguments. Everything indicates I should use this predicate as a part of remove_if function.

**How can I pass two arguments into predicate?**

I've tried:

```
auto it = remove_if(begin(v), end(v), predicate(auto[_int, _str] = Unpack(p)));
```

but it doesn't work...
Any ideas?
Thanx in advance!

Comment: Use a second lambda taking a single argument, and calls the first lambda? Use `std::bind` to set one of the arguments?

Comment: You vector holds a `std::pair<int, string>` so that's what the predicate should take. `auto predicate = [](const std::pair<int, string>& v) { return v.first != 2 && v.second != "b"; };`

Comment: Why tinker around with tuples, the pairs are good enough?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you're awesome

Comment: @Deduplicator, yes, you're right

Comment: @ super - the predicate is predefined and I can't change it. I wrote about it.

Answer (score 0):

@someprogrammerdude give me an idea (actually it was in my mind, but I couldn't "form" it:

*"Use a second lambda taking a single argument, and calls the first lambda? Use std::bind to set one of the arguments?"*

So i've just used one additional lambda to unpack the arguments and then put it in the predicate:

```
auto it = remove_if(begin(v), end(v), [predicate](pair<int, string> p) {
    return predicate(p.first, p.second);
});
```

Comment: Very well! Of course, you don't have to fill in `_int` and `_str` when you don't use them.

Comment: You might want to have your predicates accept `const&` types to prevent elements copying . Both in predicate and proxy lambdas `const pair<int, string>& p` and `[](const int& _int, const string& _str)`